# Products category detection using weka

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, data-mining

I'm working on an ecommerce application. Most of the products i have contains the category attribute, but some do not (about 70-30%). I was trying to use [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) to detect the category, but the attributes i have are strings `(name, brand, price, description, category)` so all classifiers are not working as it need the attributes to be numeric, nominal, or binary.

Did any one faced such problem before ?

Answer (score 0):

just make discrete continuous attributes and then it will work, because some of the algorithms does not work with continues values.

Answer (score 0):

Use "StringToWordVector" filter that will convert your string attribute(s) to numeric attributes.